# Reference Unity in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, unity-container

Given that Silverlight uses a cut down .net framework, can I reference Unity from a Silverlight project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special version of [Unity for Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237492.aspx) which you ou can donwload from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1623). (If you use [nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/Unity/2.1.505.2) it will reference the correnct dlls for you automatically)

However Unity for Silverlight has some restrictions:

- XML configuration is not supported.
- Because of differences in the Silverlight security model, only public types can be created and injected by the container. The desktop version allows you to also inject internal types.
- The Unity interception mechanism is not supported.

Note that (thanks the info to @Sebastian Weber) Interception is also supported since the release of EntLib Silverlight Integration Pack. [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852713%28v=pandp.51%29.aspx) for additional information.

But **you can't use the Unity "desktop dlls"**  in your SL project.

Comment: Interception is supported since the release of EntLib Silverlight Integration Pack. [See MSDN for additional information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852713%28v=pandp.51%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It exist a special version of Unity for Silverlight. You can find it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1623)

The latest version is 2.1 and is supported for Silverlight 3-5